# Using jquery validate dropdownlist and textbox, then ask for confirmation to update database

Tags: jquery

```
            <form action="">
                   <div>
                        <label><b>Text-Number </b></label>
                        <select id="text-number" value="" required >
                           <option value="" selected>Select</option>
                           <option value="1">1- One</option>
                           <option value="2">2- Two</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                
                    <div>
                        <label>Your Command</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Command" id="cmd"  value="" required />
                    </div>
               

                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit Info" id="infosubmit"/>
                        
                    </div>
            </form>
```

Here is my jquery.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('click', '#infosubmit', function () {
                   if (confirm('Are you sure?')){                   
                   
                   var txtnum= $("#text-number").val();
                   var command= $("#cmd").val();
                   
                    $("#infosubmit")[0].checkValidity(),   
                                    
                   $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: '/myapp/update_data/',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {
                            'txtnum': txtnum,
                            'cmd': cmd
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data === 'done') {

                                $("#data_table").show();
                            }
                            else {
                                                                
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
                     else {
                        $("#dbtable").show();
                                      
                    }
            });
        });
        
</script>
```

I am trying to achieve when the user click the infosubmit button. text-number dropdownlist and cmd textbox needs to be validated.
After validating, confirm dialog box should show. On clicking Yes, update the data in database.

$("#infosubmit")[0].checkValidity() -- this works, but validate after confirm dialog box.

Comment: You might want to edit your post so it becomes more clear what you're actually asking. Also, please reduce your code to what's necessary to understand the problem at hand - for example, if you don't ask anything AJAX-related, you might as well leave that part out (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). BTW: If you want to validate the form data before asking for confirmation, you should move the validation part out of and above your `if`-clause.

Comment: If I move validation above if clause, it does only the validation. Doesn't update the database table.  I don't know how to use this  $("#infosubmit")[0].checkValidity() jquery validity function above if clause.